# Mantener sesión activa con ionic y angular js

Tags: php, angularjs, ionic, api

Estoy haciendo una aplicación con los **Framework** [ionic](/questions/tagged/ionic) y [angujarjs](/questions/tagged/angujarjs), también utilizo una **API** para comunicarme con el servidor.

El caso es que quiero que cuando un usuario **Iniciar Sesión** en la Aplicación la sesión se mantenga siempre abierta aunque cierre la ventana y al abrirla nuevamente no le pida Iniciar Sesión al usuario a no ser que haya pulsado el botón desconectar.

Comment: Una cookie en angular te refieres? Lo he probado pero al cerrar la aplicación se pierde la sesión

Comment: @shaz debo indicar que es una aplicación para android/iphone

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Guarda la información del usuario dentro del móvil, puede ser un token o un identificador,

lo puedes guardar mediante `window.localStorage.setItem("idUsuario", idUsuario);`

ahora, si cuando arranca la app tu haces esto:

```
if (window.localStorage.getItem("idUsuario") != null) {
    //Hay una sesión iniciada
    //Dirige a la pantalla principal ya logueada.
} else {
    //Manda la pantalla de inicio de sesión o autentificación
}
```

Desde mi punto de vista es bueno que guardes la mayor cantidad de datos obtenidos desde la web para que después sólo accedas a ellos mediante el localStorage, así crearás una app más rápida

Comment: Muchas gracias, me ha servido de mucha ayuda.